# A puzzle from collision resolution formula in python source code

Tags: python

I feel so sorry that asked such problem here even though it looks somewhat like a mathematic issue.

The following collision resolution formula appeared in python source code, **\pythoncore\Objects\dictobject.c**

```
j = ((5*j) + 1) mod 2**i
```

The brief description for this formula is **For any initial j in range(2**i), repeating that 2**i times generates each
int in range(2**i) exactly once. In an
example that's really too small to make this entirely clear, for a table of
size 2**3 the order of indices is:**

```
0 -> 1 -> 6 -> 7 -> 4 -> 5 -> 2 -> 3 -> 0 [and here it's repeating]
```

My question is how to prove the correctness of such formula.

Comment: Maybe you should post this on math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment you're referring to contains the instruction

> see any text on random-number generation for proof

If you search a bit, you'll find that the `5*j+1 mod 2**i` recurrence is a [linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). A linear congruential generator is of the form

```
x_(n+1) = a*x_n + c (mod m)
```

For nonzero c, a linear congruential generator has full period (generating all numbers mod m) if and only if

1. c and m are relatively prime,
2. a-1 is divisible by all prime factors of m, and
3. if m is a multiple of 4, a-1 is also a multiple of 4.

This is known as the Hull-Dobell theorem. All these conditions hold for `5*j+1 mod 2**i`, so the recurrence goes through all entries in the hash table.

A full proof of the Hull-Dobell theorem can be found [here](http://chagall.med.cornell.edu/BioinfoCourse/PDFs/Lecture4/random_number_generator.pdf).